# Releasing updates weekly from a fixed number of updates in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an archive website with 200 updates whose information is all stored in a MySQL database.

I'd like to display a fixed number of them on the website, say 52, and each week, rotate one out and another one in, always keeping the total number at 52.

This is not a matter of updating the database, that information is fixed. It's a matter of displaying a 'round robin' of updates from the database 52 at a time on the website itself. I'm racking my brain trying to figure out the query.

As yet, I have not tried anything, as nothing I come up with makes sense.

From what I have researched and worked out in my own mind, hardcoding the info as start and end dates into the DB table is (to me) a silly way to go. This number of updates is fixed and I simply want them to display 52 at a time forever and ever, say every Friday.

I have a dedicated server running PHP 5.3.20 and MySQL/MySQLi are 5.5.27 (I code in MySQLi).

No matter where I look, or how much I delve into my books, I am not finding an answer to this problem. Any help will be graciously appreciated!

Comment: You might want to show us some more of your code here. But as I see it you limit the query to 52 and then make some math function that calculates an offset for the query based on the interval you're after.

Comment: what version of mysql is that ?

Comment: @jtheman I don't have code yet, I'm completely stumped on how to make this happen. I am familiar with how to select the data, how to limit it to 52 items, but not sure as to go about the math function you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to make a function calculating the number of weeks since a certain date and then add an offset to your db query from that:

```
<?php

  $starttime = strtotime("28 December 2012"); // a recent Friday
  $week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60; // time value of a week
  $posts = 200; // number of posts in your db
  $limit = 52; // number of shown posts
  $offset = floor((time()-$starttime)/$week); // rounds down difference in weeks from startdate until now
  while ($offset>$posts-$limit) $offset = $offset - ($posts-$limit); 
  // this will make the cycle start over when you have reached the end (ie offset 148)...

  ?>
```

Then just use the returning values for your offset and limit in your query:

```
  'SELECT ... LIMIT '.$offset.','.$limit;
```

Comment: I just noticed this. I'll mull this one over tomorrow though. Is there any reason the `$week` variable couldn't just be hard coded to 10,020?

Comment: No of course it could, I just named a variable to make it more readable. The same goes with $limit and $posts as I guess you won't change it...

Comment: I think this is making sense to me now. What's interesting to me is that I thought I needed some defining element in a column to make this work, and what you are showing me above somehow skips the appropritate number of entries (I hope I phrased that correctly). Very interesting.

Comment: PS - With your explanation about the variables vs. hard coding, this would let me tailor the number of posts and limits if I needed to change them, so I like that.

Comment: Good. Se my last edit from `if()` to `while()`. It makes the calculation work correctly forever.

Comment: I just was reviewing David Powers' book, PHP Solutions (2md Edition) on the LIMIT clause and suddenly it all snapped into place for me, what you are showing me here. I can't wait to try this. Shouldn't there be curly braces around the `$offset = $offset - ($posts-$limit);`` portion of the code?

Comment: Yes you can have curly braces there but it isn't needed when the whole while loop is in a single row. I personally don't use curly braces instead for several rows I would use while(): and endwhile; - I think it's cleaner. (Terrible to debug curly braces when you have many nested if's, while's and so on...) See: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Okay, that WORKED! I can not than you enough!!! I forgot one, oh, crucial piece of info...I had this set up with pagination to show 6 updates at a time per page. Using your code shows all 52 updates on one page. I now need to get this to paginate with a defined variable, say 6 entries per page. Still, this has me leaps ahead! Thank you.

Comment: I agree about the curly braces in debugging...it makes my head spin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21973/discussion-between-wordman-and-jtheman)

Comment: Sorry I went away. What about adding all your current code to a new question? Pagination would require some more thought. But I often use javascript/jQuery/ajax solutions instead of making different pages for simple lists....

Comment: I revised a post from last night, I hope this helps. Again, what I want to do is take the resulting 52 updates and page through them, say 4 per page. the revised post is [here:] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107961/paginating-a-limited-list-of-results-from-mysql-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a hard one, if you have mysql 5.5.6, you could actually directly assign a user variable to do this:

```
SET @week_nr = WEEK(NOW());
```

And then do this:

```
SELECT * FROM updates LIMIT 52 OFFSET @week_nr;
```

That would be week 0 this week.

But that doesn't work for lower versions [due to this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918), from 2005 btw...

There is a way to circumventing this limitation for other mysql, as [seen in the mysql forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,126379,133966#msg-133966) by using a prepared statement.  But that query will offset by 1 every week.

The quick equivalent of jtheman's solutions would be like:

```
   SET @offset = FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (WEEK("2012-12-28") 
                 / ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)));
```

But as you can see here [DateTime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) there is another function you could use:

```
SET @week_nr = YEARWEEK(NOW());
```

And that is year proof.

Comment: Sure this will work fine for the first year but then will reset after 1:st of January and the remaining 148 updates will never be seen...

Comment: So what is stopping you from checking the mysql docs and see if _you_ can add a year to that logic?  A stored procedure like the links say will be able to contain far more logic than now.  So you can even keep a second table to track it if you think you'll need to.

Comment: Perhaps you don't directly see the possibilities, but in a stored procedure it's very easy and lightweight to keep track of some user offset variables.  secondly, you can do a preliminary count on the table first and use math to let the offset progress in the way you want.  Like that you'll also catch rollovers, or deletes.  So it will be dynamic.  Use your imagination now.

Comment: Glenn, I appreciate your insight, but none of this makes sense to me. Thanks though.

Comment: Glenn, I wish it did. I'm decent with PHP but your knowledge level is way over mine. I'll have to do more research to understand all of this. Thanks again!

Comment: It's just SQL ..., nothing more.

Comment: Then try jtheman suggestion, he's doing what I suggest implemented in php.

Comment: Glenn, this is intriguing and I would like to learn it. The code you supplied is placed within the php tags, correct?

Comment: Not at all, it's set like a query.  You store a user variable in mysql and later retrieve it.   I've see a post from you about stored procedures so you get that, so now go and read about mysql user variables :)  It would be best you use a mysql from above the version I mentioned, all the others will hinder you from getting results.  The stored procedure isn't a great way to do it and a fix on a bug that prevents you from using a user variable in the sql LIMIT clause.

Comment: like `mysql_query('SET @week_nr = YEARWEEK(NOW());');`  You can find more about [user variables here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: Glenn, many thanks. I have a dedicated server running PHP 5.3.20 and MySQL/MySQLi are 5.5.27 (I code in MySQLi)

Comment: Welcome, That one is affected, my solution will only work from 5.5.6 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Time marking your database rows and Auto-increment will be your friend in this matter. You will need to set up a cron job if you want the sql to run every friday.

For the sql, select the rows in DESC and limit the number to 52 or use the time stamp to get the latest ones.

Comment: Roy, thank you for that. Can you point me in the right direction to understand the workings of the cron job?

Comment: PS - The data is already in the DB, it's a pre-existing DB and there are no timestamps for the entries (this thing is YEARS old). That being said, is time marking the database rows still relevant here?

Comment: I think you can solve it all with a quite simple PHP function... Cron jobs is not relevant here as I can see it...

Comment: This varies depending on your server and hosting company. You will need to look at there documentation to find out the specifics on the cron job

Comment: @jtheman I was hoping for this, as I simply wanted the page code to update the info/query when scheduled. I'm still absolutely lost on how to make this happen though.