# Can this query be altered to perform two functions?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination

Instead of posting this again, I decided to re-write and elaborate it here.

I received the following bit of code from jtheman that allows me to select 52 updates from my DB, and adds a new one and removes the old one each week. It works absolutely perfect.

His code:

```
$starttime = strtotime("28 December 2012"); // a recent Friday
  $week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60; // time value of a week
  $posts = 185; // number of posts in your db
  $limit = 52; // number of shown posts
  $offset = floor((time()-$starttime)/$week); // rounds down difference in weeks from startdate until now
  while ($offset>$posts-$limit) $offset = $offset - ($posts-$limit); 
  // this will start over when you have reached the end of the cycle ie offset 148...
```

And my query:

```
// retrieve all update details
$conn = dbConnect('query');
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM updates
WHERE flag_live = 'Y'
ORDER BY update_id DESC
LIMIT ".$offset.",".$limit;
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$uInfo = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Again, this works perfectly. The new issue is that I get 52 updates on one page and I'd like to be able to set, say 4 per page, and scroll through 13 pages instead of having one long page.

So, what I want to do is alter this query so that the 52 updates are chosen (and a new one is added and an old one is removed every Friday) but where I can show only, say, 4 at a time on the page. I realized this isn't a pagination issue as much as this is writing the query to essentially do two functions.

Can this be done with a subquery? I could just use a jQuery slider or equivalent to do the pagination but I really want to avoid that.

Many thanks!

Comment: Er...like how to make it work. How to take the code above and pull the 52 records then page through them.

Comment: the best way is to do these manipulation on the client side have a look at http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: In spite of the fact that I loathe having to usejQuery, that does look promising. But I can't have the display looking like the example table on the page you referenced. I have text and photos and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it within the PHP code (on the server side), you could add an url parameter `?page=x` where x is your page number.

Almost the same within the calculation:

```
$starttime = strtotime("28 December 2012"); // a recent Friday
$week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60; // time value of a week
$posts = 185; // number of posts in your db
$totallimit = 52; // number of shown posts (on all pages)
$limit = 4; // number of posts on each page.
$offset = floor((time()-$starttime)/$week); // rounds down difference in weeks from startdate until now
while ($offset>$posts-$totallimit) $offset = $offset - ($posts-$totallimit); 
// this will start over when you have reached the end of the cycle ie offset 148...

// get the page number (or set it to 0 if not set)
if (isset($_GET['page']) && intval($_GET['page'])) $page=intval($_GET['page']);
else $page = 0;

$offset = $offset + ($page*$limit); // correct the offset according to the page number
```

Then use your DB query without changes.

Then in your view add page links (this code works if the above is executed before):

```
<?php for($p=0;$p<ceil($totallimit/$limit);$p++): ?>
   <a href="mypage.php?page=<?php echo $p; ?>" <?php if ($p==$page) echo 'class="active"'; ?>>Page <?php echo $p+1; ?></a> |
<?php endfor; ?>
```

(Replace `mypage.php` with the correct filename of your script)

I added a class to the page anchors `active` for the currently selected page but you can do this anyway you like.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you for that! I got pagination by using a subquery, got that info last night from another of my posts, but I am definitely trying this today. Thank you so much!

Comment: That is so SMOOTH! Works absolutely perfect. I can not thank you enough!

Comment: Happy for you that it works. The datatables example is maybe a bit overkill in your case but a jquery/ajax solution for pagination is also nice. But server side solutions tend to be rock solid which can be nice in some situations.

Comment: I am so eager to learn ajax...just need the time. again, can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what youre asking for.. using this "feature" you can "switch" more options but I dont think you will really need it.. Just change `$limit=` numbers to fit your needs.

```
<?php

  $starttime = strtotime("28 December 2012"); // a recent Friday
  $week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60; // time value of a week
  $posts = 200; // number of posts in your db
  //$limit = 52; // number of shown posts

if($posts > 100) // or you can enter here $posts == 200, but it is better 2 leave it on "automatic"..
{ 
$limit = 52; //or as many you like like 30
} 
else
{ 
$limit = 6; // or as many you like ie 10 
}

  $offset = floor((time()-$starttime)/$week); // rounds down difference in weeks from     startdate until now
  while ($offset>$posts-$limit) $offset = $offset - ($posts-$limit); 
  // this will make the cycle start over when you have reached the end (ie offset 148)...

  ?>
```

Comment: Xfile, that looks as though it may work. I'll check it out tomorrow and let you know. Thank you so much!

Comment: I looked this over and decided to elaborate this post some more. Changing the `$limit` isn't going to work here because it will affect the rolling 52 updates. Many thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Yes wordman, this changing of the limit would break the original cycle of the 52 posts...